# Is there a technical limitation to creating a CSR from an existing SSL Certificate?

Tags: ssl, cryptography

I don't seem to see any software out there to do this - but I don't see any technical reason it can't be done - could this be possible?

Answer (score 0):

In short, no, there is no technical limitation, provided you still have the private key. Then again, I don't really see the point or why you would want to do it. If you have an existing, signed certificate with the associated key-pair, generating a new CSR - without generating a new key-pair - is completely redundant. You already have all you need: a key-pair, a certificate that identifies the user/website and a signature from a trusted CA.

Let's assume that you actually need to do this (for whatever reason) then the CSR will be effectively contain the same information as it did the first time around, except maybe with a different validity period. Generating a brand new key-pair periodically, and by extension a new CSR, is good security practice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the technical limitation is that you can't do it. You need the private key.